# Failed to get report from facebook api with Status 400 and error code 2601

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I met the error: **"Sorry, the report cannot be loaded successfully. Please check if your job status is completed instead of failed or running before fetching the data."**

In some days, it is ok, there is no error.
But on other days, I got the error.

I haven't found about this error anything on facebook/google search..
So, what is the problem? Expecting your feedback.
Thanks!

**My python code is:**

```
async_job = my_account.get_insights(params=params, async=True)
async_job.remote_read()

while async_job[AdReportRun.Field.async_percent_completion] < 100:
    time.sleep(1)
    async_job.remote_read()
time.sleep(1)

report = async_job.get_result()
```

**The response that I get is:**

```
Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/insights
  Params:  {}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 2601, 
        "is_transient": true, 
        "error_subcode": 1815107, 
        "error_user_msg": "Sorry, the report cannot be loaded successfully. Please check if your job status is completed instead of failed or running before fetching the data.", 
        "error_user_title": "Loading Async Ads Report Failed", 
        "message": "Error accessing adreport job.", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out? I'm stuck on this error too...